# Trailing buy code to use with FREQTRADE backtesting

Tags: python, trading, binance, cryptocurrency

I am trying to run the code with backtesting using FREQTRADE. The concept is that of a trailing stop sell but for buying (trailing buy). The backtesting results shows that no buy orders are being made.

```
def populate_indicators(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:
    # TRAILING BUY
    current_price=dataframe['close'].tail(1)
    dataframe['trailbuy'] = 0 # keep on trailing
    trailing_buy_offset = 0.005
    trailing_buy_order_enabled = True
    trailing_buy_order_started = False
    if trailing_buy_order_started:
        if current_price < trailing_buy_order_downlimit: # if price is still falling down
            trailing_buy_order_uplimit = current_price * (1 + trailing_buy_offset) # update uplimit
            trailing_buy_order_downlimit = current_price # update downlimit
            dataframe['trailbuy'] = 0 # keep on trailing 

        if current_price >= trailing_buy_order_uplimit: # if price has bounced back and now is over uplimit
            dataframe['trailbuy'] = 1 # finished trailing - buy order must be submitted immediately
            trailing_buy_order_started = False
    
    if trailing_buy_order_started == False and trailing_buy_order_enabled == True:
        trailing_buy_order_started = True
        trailing_buy_order_uplimit = current_price * (1 + trailing_buy_offset) # initialize uplimit
        trailing_buy_order_downlimit = current_price # initialize down limit
        

    return dataframe
```

I ran the code seperately in spyder using a for loop to run through the dataframe and that shows that `dataframe['trailing']` does change when a buy order is supposed to go off.

Here is the code I used in spyder to check the idea:

```
data=[[1628812800000,44400.06,44440.62,44391.87,44425.53,62.976777],[1628812860000,44428.3,44457.45,44409.06,44442.97,36.574744]]
```

(many more OHLCV entries were uses)

```
current_price=dataframe['close'].tail(1)
trailing_buy_offset = 0.005
trailing_buy_order_enabled = 1
trailing_buy_order_started = 0

for i in (range(0,len(dataframe['open']))):

dataframe['trailbuy'] = 0
current_price=dataframe['close'][i]
if trailing_buy_order_started:
    if current_price < trailing_buy_order_downlimit: # if price is still falling down
        trailing_buy_order_uplimit = current_price * (1 + trailing_buy_offset) # update uplimit
        trailing_buy_order_downlimit = current_price # update downlimit
        dataframe['trailbuy'] = 0 # keep on trailing

    if current_price >= trailing_buy_order_uplimit: # if price has bounced back and now is over uplimit
        dataframe['trailbuy'] = 1 # finished trailing - buy order must be submitted immediately
        trailing_buy_order_started = 0

if trailing_buy_order_started == 0 and trailing_buy_order_enabled == 1:
    trailing_buy_order_started = 1
    trailing_buy_order_uplimit = current_price * (1 + trailing_buy_offset) # initialize uplimit
    trailing_buy_order_downlimit = current_price # initialize down limit

    
print(dataframe['trailbuy'].tail(1))
```

I'm not if there is maybe an issue with my positioning of the code in the strategy.py file used by freqtrade. Any help will be very much appreciated.